# How do I to target a single value in firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble figuring out how to target a single object in the firebase database. For example, I want to have a specific word/definition shown when I click an index card. I'm using this to store the data:

```
wordVal = $("#word").val();
defVal = $("#def").val();

data = firebase.database().ref("indexCards");
data.push( { 'word': wordVal, 'definition': defVal } );
```

and this to retrieve it:

```
data.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val().word);   
    console.log(snapshot.val().definition);
});
```

This gives me the whole list of words and definitions. I want to refer to specific words and specific definitions, separately. The docs say that I can reference the specific values by doing this - `firebase.database().ref("child/path")`.

But my question is...how can I reference the path when the parents are those random numbers and letters (see below)? I know that these are unique IDs generated by firebase, but I don't know how to access them like I'd access ordinary objects.

```
{
  "-KQIOHLNsruyrrnAhqis" : {
    "definition" : "person, place, thing",
    "word" : "noun"
  },
  "-KQIOO7Wtp2d5v2VorqL" : {
    "definition" : "device for photos",
    "word" : "camera"
  },
  "-KQISp4WMnjABxQayToD" : {
    "definition" : "circus act",
    "word" : "clown"
  },
  "-KQITC9W1lapBkMyiL7n" : {
    "definition" : "device used for cutting",
    "word" : "scissors"
  }
}
```

[image: A photo of my Firebase database]

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no problem, I just added the JSON text

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
data = firebase.database().ref('indexCards').orderByChild('word').equalTo('noun')
```

It is self-explanatory, we get reference to indexCards where value of key *word* is equal *noun*, so it will return object with key *-KQHZ3xCHTQjuTvonSwj*

Link to [Firebase docs: Retrieve data - Sorting and Filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the initial push into an object then call the object later. ie

To PUSH data: 
firebase.database().ref().push( { 'word': wordVal, 'definition': defVal } )

To UPDATE data or call it later:
firebase.database().ref("indexCards").set({})

or in this case: 
data.set({})